# git keeps adding a symlink directory and then removing it every other time I git add

Tags: git, symlink

My folder structure is like this:

my_source

- git repo
- some folder that works fine
- a symlink to another folder

First time I ever add: I run `git add .` and it adds all of the stuff it should.

Second time: I run `git add .` and discover git has removed the contents of the symlinked folder from its repo.

Third time: I run `git add .` and it adds contents of symlinked folder again.

Then it keeps alternating. Adding symlink folder contents, removing them, adding them, removing them. Any ideas?

Comment: What is your `core.symlinks` option?

Comment: Whatever the default is. I didn't know that existed.